# Something I don't understand about 'use strict' and this

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, everything you declare in JavaScript, belongs to the global object (unless you declare something inside of an object, then the object would belong to the window object, and whatever you declare inside of it, to the object), so, inside of a browser environment, the global object is `window`.

Say you declare:
`var x = 'hi'`

This could be accessed with:

`x`

**OR**

`window.x`

And both are absolutely the same, right? So why, with `'use strict'`, when returning `this` from a 'global' variable, can I only get the `window` object if I specify that said function belongs to `window`?

```
function fun() {
    'use strict';
    return this;
}

fun(); // undefined
window.fun(); // window object
// Aren't both absolutely the same?
```

Also, why does this function return `undefined`, if the function is supposed to belong to `obj`?

```
obj = {
    method: function () {
        'use strict';
        function yeah() { // Doesn't this belong to obj?
            return this;  // It certainly doesn't seem that 'yeah'
        }                 // belongs to window.
        return yeah();
    }
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why, with 'use strict', when returning this from a 'global' variable, can I only get the window object if I specify that said function belongs to window?

You can get the `window` object by simply accessing it as `window`.

It won't be the value of `this` because that feature made it easy to accidentally write insecure code and came with a performance cost.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript):

> Not only is automatic boxing a performance cost, but exposing the
>   global object in browsers is a security hazard, because the global
>   object provides access to functionality that "secure" JavaScript
>   environments must restrict. Thus for a strict mode function, the
>   specified this is not boxed into an object, and if unspecified, this
>   will be undefined

---

> Also, why does this function return undefined, if the function is supposed to belong to obj?

While `yeah` is in the scope of a function that is a method of `obj`, `yeah` itself isn't a method of `obj` as you aren't calling it as one.

i.e. because you are calling `yeah()` and not `obj.yeah()` (or `yeah.call(obg)` etc).

That has nothing to do with `"use strict"` though.

Comment: So `this` is strictly for object methods, correct? Anything else just belongs to a scope? Also, why would calling `setTimeout`, without the `window.setTimeout` syntax, inside of a method with `use strict`, return the `window` object? Shouldn't it also return undefined?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to be that way because `setTimeout` doesn't run, itself, in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside of a function is supposed to return the object that the function was invoked on (using the `obj.method()` syntax).

Without `use strict` the value of `this` will be set to `window` if the function is called any other way (for example by just doing `func()` instead of `obj.func()`). That is quite confusing. `use strict` makes sure that `this` is properly undefined when the function is not called as an object method.